# How to manage multiple Azure subscriptions efficiently?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay, azure-management

The Maximum number of basic / standard namespaces per Azure subscription are 100 as per the following link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas). However I need more and hence the below questions:

1. Is taking a second azure subscription the only way to go over 100 namespaces or is there any other way?
2. If I take a second and third Azure subscription, how do I keep all the subscriptions in sync. For example if I change something on first, do I specifically need to do that on the others also? Is there a central portal to manage this more efficiently?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas):

> Subsequent requests for additional basic / standard namespaces are rejected by the portal.

Contact Microsoft first to see if the limit is hard or can be lifted. Some Azure services impose limitations to ensure customers don't shoot themselves in the foot and overspend.

> how do I keep all the subscriptions in sync.

Manually / scripted. There's no other way to know what your needs are to automate it on the subscription level by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you really need so many namespaces? I am assuming you will be creating separate queues, topics, etc in each one of them. Even the basic tier has a base charge of $10/month. When you have more than a 100, these charges will add up. In my case, I am utilizing the same service bus queue for multiple types of data. I use the label property of a brokered message to distinguish the different types of messages. In my case, I am using Azure functions to read from the queue. Here is how my function looks like:

```
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%QueueName%", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "MyConnection")]BrokeredMessage myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    // BrokeredMessage properties
    var label = myQueueItem.Label;        
    var contentType = myQueueItem.ContentType;
    var messageId = myQueueItem.MessageId;

    // Custom properties we can add to BrokeredMessage
    var file = myQueueItem.Properties["FileName"].ToString();

    switch (myQueueItem.Label)
    {
        case "Label 1":

            // Do Something
            break;

        case "Label 2":

            // Do Something else
            break;

        default:
            Log.Debug("Unknown label: {@Label}", label);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: Was able to get the namespace quota increased by talking to Azure support.